# multi-typed rest parameter type definition

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a typescript definition file for this javascript library: https://github.com/CRogers/pun

The problem currently lies with the function `pun.match`, which alternates every other argument as an ADT object or as an anonymous function. I'd like to describe this in a typescript definition as something along the lines of:

```
export function match<K extends ADT, V>([syntax here for ...: K, () => V]): V;
```

I suspect this isn't really possible. If it isn't, is there some workaround I can do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I suspect this isn't really possible. If it isn't, is there some workaround I can do?

Not possible. Workaround use `any[]`:

```
export function match(...args:any[]): any;
```

Alternatively you can define it for the first few (n) cases:

```
declare function match<K extends ADT, V>(k: K, v:() => V, k2?: K, v2?:() => V, k3?: K, v3?:() => V): V;
```

Comment: I meant workaround that still provides type safety. But I suppose that's a little too much to hope for. Thanks.

Comment: @Peter added another workaround with a bit more safety. But there is a tradeoff